# Strict string searching from dictionary in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

This program reads a large directory of text files. Each file is to be searched for a specific string (a dollar amount number with exactly two decimal places).
I am running the following code the purpose of which is to determine if a particular dollar amount is in a text file:

```
d = {}
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
  d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)

import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    string = d.get(filename, "!@#$%^&*")
    if string in open(filename, 'r').read():
        with open("outfile.txt", 'a') as out:
            out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(filename, string, 1))
    else: 
        with open("ibes_in.txt", 'a') as out:
            out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(filename, string, 0))
```

numbers.txt contains a list of filenames (.txt files) and a dollar amounts. The dollar amounts string will either be in the file of the filename or they wont.

For the most part this code works perfectly except it finds matches to numbers that have more than two digits of cents.  For example if the search string is 1.42 I don't want it to match 1.423.

If the search string is 1.42

Sample input:

"The company reported $1.42 of..."

Sample result: true

Sample input:

"The company saw growth of 1.427 ..."

sample result: false

The use of dollar signs is not universal and sometimes the number is encased in () to indicate a negative. I believe regular expressions \b is the right way to mark the ending of the two digits but I'm not sure how to implement it in the code I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can do this with a regular expression and `\b`:

```
if re.search('\\b' + re.escape(string) + '\\b', open(filename, 'r').read()):
```

Comment: Thank you this replaces the >>>>if string in open(filename, 'r').read(): ? Does it need any other changes?

Comment: Indeed it replaces that, and no other changes are needed.